# gmail-gui doesn't work correctly in Ubuntu 23.10.1

Tags: software-installation, configuration, browser, 23.10

I try to connect my Gmail with `gmail-gui` in Ubuntu, but when I enter my email address it shows me

> java script is disabled

I tested another program (gmail-desktop) but it's also having this problem.

How can fix this error?

[image]